Split and Arrange columns pandas
I have one raw column like this: enter image description here
variant_label
XL / White
Black/ S
White / S
L/ White
X/ Black
Black / XL
White / M
Black / M
Black / M
Black / L
XL / White
I want to separate it into 2 columns:  Color and Size enter image description here
Color   Size
White   XL
Black   S
White   L
Black   X
...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You could use something like this considering variant_label does not have consistent data entries (so sometimes we have Black / L and sometimes we have XL / White:
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'variant_label': ['XL / White', 'Black/ S', 'White / S', 'L/ White', 'X/ Black', 
                          'Black / XL', 'White / M', 'Black / M', 'Black / M', 'Black / L', 'XL / White']}

# Creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define possible size values
sizes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX']

# Function to determine size and color
def split_variant_label(label):
    parts = [part.strip() for part in label.split('/')]
    size = next((part for part in parts if part in sizes), None)
    color = next((part for part in parts if part not in sizes), None)
    return pd.Series([color, size])

# Apply the function to the DataFrame
df[['Color', 'Size']] = df['variant_label'].apply(split_variant_label)

# Display the result
print(df[['Color', 'Size']])

Here:

Possible Sizes: The sizes list contains possible size values. You can expand this list if needed.
Custom Function: The split_variant_label function splits the variant_label into parts and then identifies the size and color by checking against the sizes list.
Applying the Function: The apply() method is used to apply the custom function to each row of the variant_label column.

